# Сложить datetime.time с datetime.time в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, время, datetime

Доброго времени суток!

Прошу подсказать как проще всего сложить переменные tm1 и tm2 в следующем коде:

```
from datetime import datetime, time

tm1 = time(0,30)
tm2 = time(1,30)
print(tm1 + tm2) # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

Спасибо.

Comment: а что вы хотите получить? объекты time - это не промежуток времени, а время суток.

Comment: Вам вероятно нужен [объект `timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) – его можно складывать и вычитать друг с другом и с объектами date/time/datetime.

Comment: Задача получить разницу между временами. На данный момент нашел только одно решение – через timedelta, но возможно подскажите более удобный способ?

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать `timedelta`

```
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

tm3 = timedelta(hours=0, minutes=30)
tm4 = timedelta(hours=1, minutes=30)
print(tm3 + tm4)  #  2:00:00
```

Comment: Именно так и делаю, другого варианта получается нет?

Comment: Если результат еще необходимо проверить (tm3 + tm4) > 1h, то  аналогично сравнивать с timedelta?

Comment: @pyok чтобы "по-питонски" скорее всего нет. Если только влоб, сплитовать даты на ч, м, с, складывать и форматировать

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое.

Comment: Сравнивать с дельтами тоже, да

Comment: Просто недавно перешел на питон с более низкоуровневого, а реализация схожа с golang, подумал в питоне более простое решение. Еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно сложить два объекта именно типа `time`, можно использовать вот такой самописный вариант функции сложения времени:

```py
from datetime import time

tm1 = time(0,30)
tm2 = time(1,30)

def sum_time(time1, time2):
    th1, tm1, ts1 = time1.hour, time1.minute, time1.second
    th2, tm2, ts2 = time2.hour, time2.minute, time2.second

    th3, tm3, ts3 = th1 + th2, tm1 + tm2, ts1 + ts2
    tm3, ts3 = tm3 + ts3 // 60, ts3 % 60
    th3, tm3 = th3 + tm3 // 60, tm3 % 60

    # На всякий случай. Вдруг больше дня получится =)
    th3 = th3 % 24

    return time(th3, tm3, ts3)

print(tm1, tm2)
print(sum_time(tm1, tm2))
```

Результат:

```
00:30:00 01:30:00
02:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть использован - `timedelta`. Вы можете добавить список периодов времени.

```
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

#enter a list of time intervals period_times = ((*, *, *),(*, *, *), ...)
#where 2 hours
#where 35 minutes
#where 10 seconds

period_times = (
                (0, 35, 10),
                (0, 35, 55)
                )


tm = timedelta(minutes=0) # 00:00:00

for i in period_times:
    tm += timedelta(hours=i[0], minutes=i[1], seconds=i[2])

print(tm)  #  1:11:05
```